# Make an input keyboard without enter in Telegraf (node.js)

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegraf

How can I make an input keyboard than doesn't have automatically enters, you'll see, in a regular telegraf bot you use

```
ctx.reply('One Hi', Markup.keyboard(['1', '2', '3'])
```

But when you do, there is an enter after 1, and after 2, basicly, they are in different lines, I wanna make to buttons in the same line, can someone help me?

Comment: Please accept the answer as the correct one if it answers your question

Answer (score 3):

Of course, you can do that... Markup.keyboard is defined to receive an array (`array[]`) and arrays of arrays (`array[][]`).

Just put your array of buttons inside another array as such to specify you want them in the same line.

```
ctx.reply('One Hi', Markup.keyboard([['1', '2', '3']]);
```

When using array[][] to specify buttons, the first array will indicate the lines (rows)  and the second array will indicate the columns... By saying `Markup.keyboard([['1', '2', '3']]`, you are saying I need one line with three columns in it, while previously you were saying, I need three lines with one buttons each.